# sveltekit packaged component styled using tailwind css (actually daisy ui) loses styling when consumed

Tags: tailwind-css, sveltekit

I have a component library, `@cozemble/data-paginated-editor` that is styled using `daisyui` and an app `@cozemble/frontend-main-app` that is also styled using `daisyui` and uses `@cozemble/data-paginated-editor`.

However, some of the styles applied in `@cozemble/data-paginated-editor` don't show up.

I have just learned from [this post that](https://adamtuttle.codes/blog/2023/tailwind-svelte-design-system/) when compiling my app, tailwind compiles out unused styles, so unless I configure `tailwind.config.cjs` to look into my component library in `node_modules`, the styles will disappear.

So I did this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}',
    './node_modules/@cozemble/data-paginated-editor/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require("@tailwindcss/typography"), require('daisyui')
  ],
}
```

It took minutes (one or two maybe) for the app to start, because it was compiling I assume, but then the styles did show.

This is a terrible terrible solution, surely you agree?  I have a dozen components, many of which depend on each other.  Do I really have to do all this leg work?

What options do I have?

I am considering just loading daisyui from the CDN in all my packages.  Their [website warns against](https://daisyui.com/docs/cdn/) this due to the large size of the css file.  Its 112KB, which is a fair trade in my mind, for shareable components that carry their styling.